# Javascript setter and getter over prototype initialization function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

when initializing a javascript object, I want to get the attribute value from a function execution.

By the time, my object looks like this:

```
var objectName = function(){}

objectName.prototype.initialize = function() {
  this.attribute = functionOne();

  functionOne() {
    return httpRequest();
  }
}
```

So obviously, every time I call on `instance.attribute`, `functionOne` gets executed, and because it is an async function, the result is `undefined`. I know I need getter and setter methods for this to happen, but what is the correct way on doing this keeping this prototype structure.

I tried the following

```
objectName.prototype.initialize = function() {
  this.attribute = undefined;
  Object.defineProperty(this, "attribute", {
    get: function() { return this.attribute },
    set: functionOne()
  });
}
```

But when I call on `instance.attribute` I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
  at objectName.get [as attribute] (file.js:6)

line 6: get: function() { return this.geoData },
```

Comment: `this.attribute { get }` calls `this.attribute { get }` calls `this.attribute { get }` calls .. use a different name for the backing property, like `_attribute`..

Comment: Also, the original code is equivalent to: `this.attribute = httpRequest()` because `functionOne` is invoked *immediately*.. so not sure what the goal is..

Answer (score 0):

```
const objectName = function(){}

const objectName.prototype.initialize = function() {
  this.attribute = undefined;
  Object.defineProperty(this, "attribute", {
    get: function() { return this.attribute },
    set: functionOne()
  });
}

const instance = new objectOne()

// This is infinitely recursive
instance.attribute 
// because instance.attribute invokes attribute getter, which returns instance.attribute
// which invokes attribute getter, which returns instance.attribute, which invokes ......
// which "eventually" (actually within a few microseconds) overflows the stack
```

---

```
var objectName = function(){}

objectName.prototype.initialize = function() {
  // Function called immediately when you initialize. Result is
  // essentially cached to this.attribute.
  this.attribute = functionOne();

  // returns whatever httpRequest returns
  function functionOne() {
    return httpRequest();
  }
}
```

Since `httpRequest` is obviously async, there are basically 2 types of returns you can expect:

1. A new or well-maintained module will probably offer a promise API, in which case you can call `.then` on the returned promise.

```
instance.attribute.then(function(attr) {
  doSomethingWithAttribute(attr)
})

// or 

(async function() {
  const attr = await instance.attribute
  doSomethingWithAttribute(attr)
})()
```

2. Older modules will probably use a callback system. So you need to pass in a function right away.

```
var objectName = function(){}

objectName.prototype.initialize = function() {
  // Notice I removed the parens here, this is no longer just about
  // immediate invocation. We need a callback to give to httpRequest.
  // so now attribute is basically an alias for functionOne. You could
  // instead accept a callback to attribute and pass it on to functionOne.
  this.attribute = functionOne;

  functionOne(callback) {
    return httpRequest(callback);
  }
}

// Just for reference, but not relevant to the question, this is a more concise
// version of the function above assigned to objectName.prototype.initialize.
const equivalentInitialize = {
  this.attribute = function(callback) {
    return httpRequest(callback);
  };
}

const instance = new objectOne()
instance.attribute(doSomethingWithAttribute)
```

To make this more composable, you could wrap the callback API in a promise.

```
var objectName = function(){}

objectName.prototype.initialize = function() {
  this.attribute = new Promise(resolve => {
    httpRequest(resolve)
  })
}

const instance = new objectName()
instance.atttribute
  .then(doSomethingWithAttribute)
```

Better yet, you can forget about all this getter and setter nonsense, which in Javascript does not even provide the safety you think it does.

```
// Making some wild guesses about api here, since I don't what you are using 
// here to make a request

httpRequest({ url, method, apiKey })
  .then(doSomethingWithResponse)
```

Comment: Even though this is correct, that doesn't prevent to get the function executed every time I need the instance attribute value, what is i'm trying to prevent. Is that correct?

Comment: @jtomasrl I don't understand your question here.